# with cer file working and sign string files or xml files. Please help us

Tags: string, x509certificate, sign

I have some problems with x509certificates class.

These codes are working with usb stick. But not working ".cer" files.

Public Function signString(ByVal msg As String, ByVal imzasahibi As String) As String

```
    Dim unicode As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Dim msgBytes As Byte() = unicode.GetBytes(msg)

    Dim signerCert As X509Certificate2 = GetSignerCert(imzasahibi)
    Dim encodedSignedCms As Byte() = SignMsg(msgBytes, signerCert)

    Dim result As String = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedSignedCms)

    If Not VerifyMsg(msgBytes, encodedSignedCms) Then
        Throw New Exception("Any problems")
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

---

Public Function MesajImzala(ByVal msg As String, ByVal imzasahibi As String) As String

Dim sertifikamiz As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("certificateFiles/testFile.cer")

Dim signerCert As X509Certificate2 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(sertifikamiz)

```
    Dim unicode As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Dim msgBytes As Byte() = unicode.GetBytes(msg)

    Dim encodedSignedCms As Byte() = SignMsg(msgBytes, signerCert)

    Dim result As String = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedSignedCms)

    If Not VerifyMsg(msgBytes, encodedSignedCms) Then
        Throw New Exception("Any problems")
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

if you want i send files. Thank you all...

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate' türündeki nesne 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2' türüne atılamadı.

Answer (score 0):

.CER files usually contain only the certificate without a private key. To sign data you must have the private key. This is why you can't sign the data with just a .cer file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to do it from a file. Any suggestions you all right?

Comment: @user2396436 If you have only CER file, then you can NOT do any signing as you don't have a private key. If you have a private key (eg in a separate file), then you can convert CER + key to PFX, then load PFX and use it for signing. These topics have been discussed here on SO several times each already.